# replace NA in date column with blank

Tags: r, date, missing-data

I have a date column in my dataframe with some NA values. I am trying to replace this NA values with blank using the command, `df$FirstDate[is.na(df$FirstDate)] <- " "`
I am getting an error

> Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Not sure how to fix this error. Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

Here's the `dput` output from date column

```
df = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing some of the data, try adding dput(df$FirstDate) to your question

Comment: Do you really have `NA` or is it `<NA>`?

Comment: @Pascal,  i have NA in my date column

Comment: `as.Date()` knows how to manage `NA`. See the output of `as.Date(NA)`. But this function expects a certain structure of character, to coerce this character into date. `" "` is a character, with no distinct structure and `as.Date()` doesn't know how to deal with this, i.e. `as.Date(" ")` gives the same error you mentioned.

Comment: @Pascal, nice answer. I see my problem now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `df$FirstDate` column is of class `Date`.

This means that any non-`NA` values you try to assign in this column will be coerced into class `Date`, and in the process of coercion you are seeing this error because the string `" "` is not in a standard unambiguous format for conversion into class `Date`.

If you are absolutely set on replacing `NAs` with spaces, convert `df$FirstDate` column to class `character` first like so:

```
> df$FirstDate <- as.character(df$FirstDate)
```

Now, go ahead and run:

```
> df$FirstDate[is.na(df$FirstDate)] <- " "
```

Comment: that I know, I am not too excited about converting date to char, I have to deal with format, origin and those issues while converting char to date back again later, I prefer something that works on the column with class date.

Comment: Can you provide some motivation for why you want to replace `NAs` with this specific string `" "`?

Comment: From the documentation for the class `Date`: "Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates...It is intended that the date should be an integer..." If you want to insert a string into a `Date` vector, you'll need to coerce it into class `character`. If you don't like how `NAs` look, you'll either have to impute missing values or replace them with a standard missing value like `1970-01-01`.

Comment: i see the problem here, you and Pascal explained this perfectly. I am not very keen on replacing the NA with blanks now. My priority is to retain the class date, converting to char, then replacing NA is too much work. I fine as is

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar cosmetic issue.

Try converting the column to `as.character.Date`.

```
df$FirstDate <- as.character.Date(df$FirstDate)
```